# How to include webpack file in create-react-file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app to start a react project. In the directory created there is no webpack.congif file. Do I need to add it and how should I add it? Also when I run yarn build, it builds a build folder for me. But How should I change the code of the build script? It is no where in the script.

[image]

Comment: Did you have a chance to read [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) documentation?

Comment: Yes I read it. But there is no mention of how to edit config files and also how to include them. I also want to implement ACL and server side rendering to CRA. Is that possible to do?

Comment: _webpack.config_ file will be available after you run _yarn/npm eject_ command. Read more about `eject` command

Answer (score 0):

Create React App is a zero-configuration boilerplate + tools.

From Readme file of `create-react-app`

> You don’t need to install or configure tools like Webpack or Babel.
> They are preconfigured and hidden so that you can focus on the code.

If you need to make changes to webpack config, consider the following.

- [How to customize create-react-app without ejecting](https://daveceddia.com/customize-create-react-app-webpack-without-ejecting/)
- [Create your custom fork of create-react-app](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/)

If none of these works for you, you have an option to get all configuration options by ejecting the app.

You gotta run

```
yarn eject
```

or

```
npm run eject
```

From documentation

> npm run eject
> Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!
>
> If you aren’t satisfied with the build tool and configuration choices, you can eject at any time. This command will remove the single build dependency from your project.
>
> Instead, it will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. All of the commands except eject will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point you’re on your own.